# ¿Es posible modificar el tamaño de la cache de Firebase en Android?

Tags: android, firebase

Es posible, de alguna forma, settear el tamaño de la caché de firebase en Android, actualmente es de 10 MB.

Comment: Acabo de encontrar esta respuesta de una persona que supone ser ingeniero de Firebase; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39213625/firebase-realtime-database-maximum-cache-size-in-android  , no esperemos más, solo 10MB =P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tu pregunta es una duda que yo también tenía al trabajar con Firebase:

> [Por default, 10MB de datos previamente sincronizados podrán ser almacenados en caché.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities)

Lo que te puedo comentar es que por el momento no existe alguna forma o método expuesto para realizar este cambio.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase

seguramente será implementando cuando se tenga un módelo de pago haha! =(